# unable to open my Sharepoint online-website in Sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, error

I have as admin created a modern web site SPO . I try to login to the site using SharePoint designer 2013. But I am not able to login, I am getting this error:

```
The request could not be completed by the server.
```

and

```
403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is multi-factor authentication enabled on your tenant? have you enabled SP designer settings for this side? Have tried clearing cache of SP designer?

Comment: yas, I have done that, but i can't to login to SPD .

Answer (score 0):

Please check as following:

1. Make sure you have enabled SharePoint Designer for the site via

   `Site settings > SharePoint Designer Settings > Enable SharePoint Designer`.

   [image]
2. Make sure you have allowed **custom script** on this site.

   Run the command below as a global admin

   `Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0`

   Reference:
   [To allow custom script on other SharePoint sites.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fAllow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f#to-allow-custom-script-on-other-sharepoint-sites)